# How to set text property for any type of web controls from web page dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0, web-controls, system.web.ui.webcontrols

I need to set text property for any type controls(Ex. Textbox,Label,HyperLink..etc) from my web page dynamically. Here is my code

```
foreach (string id in List<IdCollection>)
{
Control ctrl = (this.Page.FindControl(id)); // Control should be HtmlGenericControl or WebControl.
ctrl.Text=???(This property is not available for Control Class)..
}
```

I dont need to check each and every control type for set text property as like as following codes

```
if(ctrl is TextBox)
{
((TextBox)ctrl).Text="test";
}
```

or

```
 if(ctrl.GetType()==typeof(TextBox))
{
 ((TextBox)ctrl).Text="test";
}
```

> Is there any other way to set text property as simple, just like as the
>   following code

```
WebControl wbCntrl=(WebControl)ctrl;
wbCntrl.Tooltip="tooltip"; //// This is possible
wbCntrl.Text="test" ??? //// But this is not possible
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# 4.0 (VS 2010) then you could use the "dynamic" keyword:

```
foreach (string id in List<IdCollection>)
{
  dynamic ctrl = (this.Page.FindControl(id)); 
  ctrl.Text = "test";
}
```

Obviously you would get a runtime exception if you try to do this on a control that's missing the Text property.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.. But im using C# 3.5. So 'dynamic' doesn't support Text property.